# Play local video file in electron html5 video player using node.js fs.readStream()

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am developing a video player application, which plays video videos (.mp4) from the local filesystem using node.js and electron (therefore I am using chromium's html5 video player).

Playing video videos larger than 2GB seems to be a problem with my current approach.

I used to read the local video files using fs.readFileSync and pass that Blob to the video player, like in this code:

```
this.videoNode = document.querySelector('video');
const file: Buffer = fs.readFileSync(video.previewFilePath);
this.fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([file]));
this.videoNode.src = this.fileURL;
```

This does work for video files smaller that 2GB. Files larger than 2GB trigger the following error:

```
ERROR RangeError [ERR_FS_FILE_TOO_LARGE]: File size (2164262704) is greater than possible Buffer: 2147483647 bytes
    at tryCreateBuffer (fs.js:328)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:364)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (electron/js2c/asar.js:597)
```

I believe the solution is to pass a ReadStream to the html5 video player using fs.readStream(). Unfortunately I cannot find any documentation on how to pass this stream to the video player.

Comment: See: https://medium.com/better-programming/video-stream-with-node-js-and-html5-320b3191a6b6

Comment: @Terry I am looking for a way to pass the file (which is available in the local filesystem) directly to the video player. I'd like to avoid creating a http-server if possible.

Comment: Why are you using `fileStream` rather than just linking to the video? I use `video.js` to play local videos and it works great. I can post code if you like.

Comment: @NoGrabbing This seems to work on a first try (with a small video file), but it requires disabling webSecurity in Electron, which might be a security problem.

Comment: I wondered if using a stream was due to file size. I don't know if linking means the entire file is loaded into memory. Re: security – yes, I guess. I on;y use local content in my apps so that is not an issue. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

As the topic says you are using electron and from the above comments it is clear that you are avoiding a server. It seems that if you are just creating an offline video player then you are just making things complex. Why are you creating a buffer and then creating a new url? You can achieve this by simply getting the video path and using it as src attribute of video object.
Your code should look like this-

```
var path="path/to/video.mp4"; //you can get it by simple input tag with type=file or using electron dialogs
this.videoNode = document.querySelector('video');//it should be a video element in your html
this.videoNode.src=path;
this.videoNode.oncanplay=()=>{
  //do something...
}
```

This will handle complete file and you dont need to disable webPreference given that videoNode is the video element in html file.

You can take a look at this open source media player project made using electron-

https://github.com/HemantKumar01/ElectronMediaPlayer

Disclaimer: i am the owner of the above project and everyone is invited to contribute to it