# display a video file after decryption in node js using crypto js

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, electron

i am using electron and node js and trying to decrypt an encrypted file using crypto js, but i don't want to save it on user's local hard drive, i want to display it on video tag as i am reading it, meaning i don't want to use fs.createWriteStream after decryption, here is what i tried:

```
    const decipher = crypto.createDecipher('des-ecb', 'a password');
    const decInput = fs.createReadStream("encrypted video");
    var file = decInput.pipe(decipher);
    var file2 = fs.createReadStream(file);
```

is such thing is even possible? if i want to display the video i must have its url for source of video tag, but i can't make an URL for that file, and i cant even read it because it says object is passed to the **fs.createReadStream** and it says param must be string(path) or buffer or etc...

NOTE: the encryption and decryption works just fine so i ignored the rest of the code...

Answer (score 0):

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57009575/play-local-video-file-in-electron-html5-video-player-using-node-js-fs-readstream) might already suit your needs. You already have the stream ready, let frontend reads it so that video is stored in the browser.

Comment: problem is when i use URL.createObjectURL on my file it returns an unknown format file... not my video